# How to use OR condition in Redis MATCH operation

Tags: redis

I would like to know how to use a or condition in a MATCH Operation in Redis

`redis-cli SCAN 0 MATCH "a*" | "b*"` is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis' pattern matching is [glob-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and thus does not offer the equivalent of an OR operation.

You'll have to perform a `SCAN` for each of the ORed patterns, or use a Lua script for more matching power (see the [`EVAL` command](https://redis.io/commands/eval) and then the example https://github.com/itamarhaber/redis-lua-scripts/blob/master/scanregex.lua).